# Please..help .Does restore point also keep, index entries and file permissions?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, windows-restore

Lap1-OS-Windows 7 and Lap2- Win10
Here's what happened...
I have two laptops, and, on one laptop, started having screen display
issues, the top corner, was showing black...so, had to give it to repair..
**before that**, I just **created a system restore point** and took out the
internal hard-disk, before giving laptop for screen repair...

And while laptop was in repair shop, **I needed some files from the Lap1-s internal harddisk-downloads folder,** to be copied to my, another laptop, so I plugged hard disk in external reader, and plugged to laptop to copy...
When I tried to open tried to open **Lap1-User folder**, it showed **"access denied, click allow to edit permission and access"** dialogue-box--I didn't think much back then, and **clicked on Allow**.. and copied the downloads folder..

And when I got the laptop repaired back, I plugged the internal hardisk
and started it . It booted into **chkdsk screen, where it showed like, indexing entried, deleting entries, making attribute changes..etc...** I panicked..but let it complete.. after chkdsk completion, the system booted fine.. and everything seems fine like software etc.. but now I'm thinking...**should I apply the restore point, I had previously made..?**.will the restore point, also restore file attributes, that got corrupted, due to me plugging hardisk in other laptop...

---

**TLDR**

So to wrap up, does system restore point, saves index entries and file
attributes, that can be applied.. will it undo the changes made by chkdsk,
will it repair the file permissions changes, that was made from plugging
harddisk in other lap..

Or does, applying system restore., that was taken before, folder
permission changes, and before chkdsk, if it is applied afted chkdsk . Will
mess up things, even more .

---

Answer (score 2):

System Restore will probably not help in your case.

System Restore only takes snapshots of system files, device drivers,
installed programs and Windows registry keys, as well as some `.exe`
files. It's more concerned with file backup, rather than with folder
permissions and is very partial.

If everything is working fine, I would suggest to do nothing at all.
Only if you encounter problems with Windows, you might try
System Restore. Note that when applying a System Restore point,
Windows will first take another System Restore snapshot, so if this
causes a new mess you can return to your previous mess by applying
that snapshot.

In case of serious problems, have a look at the article
[How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

It's best of course to upgrade from Windows 7 to a newer version,
if supported by your computer model.